# How to search within all headers in chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I was learning about Chrome developer tools from [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) official tutorial.

At one place, the tutorial was able to search through all headers:
[image]

But for me, it is searching only through the Responses:

[image]

It was not listing single header with the search string:

[image]

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for:

```
has-response-header:cache-control
```